# Stripe Success_URL Querystring

Tags: stripe-payments, querystringparameter

I have implemented a checkout that defines the success_url.  I have added {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} to the querystring and it works fine.  I would like to include other information that would allow me to tie that response to the user in my database that made the payment.  For example, customer email.  Is session_id the only variable that can be included or is there a list somewhere?

This URL works:

```
'success_url' =>  'https://www.psychology.com/personality/lizard/success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
```

```
    I tried {email}
    {customer}.{email}
    {customer->email}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only template variable is [`CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-success_url) on the `success_url` and I do not believe you can add `CUSTOMER_EMAIL`. This [document](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) shows how you can customize your success page to show the customer's email address on the page. However, I do think think that is what you're looking for. If you're trying to attain the customer's email to save to your database, then, I recommend that you listen to [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) or retrieve the customer [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve). Stripe webhooks send events that you can listen to and with Checkout, you can listen to [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_details-email) for instance and look at the [`customer_details.email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_details-email)